Add p-value breaks to a gene oncology dot plot
I am so close to finishing up a gene oncology-gene ratio figure for a lab assignment, but I am struggling with adjusting my p-value breaks. I'd like to have control to having p-value range from 0.001 to 0.1 but I am unable to adjust them.
Here is my code for this simple graph. I tried breaks = c(#, #, #, #) but it didn't change anything.
Here is a sample dataset



Description
Gene_Ratio
padj
Counts




PC
0.025518341
0.019979193
48


MC
0.045188729
0.002983554
85


AC
0.003721425
0.010350122
7


RC
0.005316321
0.002091164
63


VC
0.023923445
0.013849514
23



ggplot(data=Try2, aes(x=GeneRatio, y=reorder(Description, GeneRatio), 
                      color=padj, size=Count)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_gradient(low="red", high="blue") +
  theme_bw() +
  ylab("Description") +
  xlab("Gene Ratio") +
  ggtitle ("GO enrichment analysis - Top 30 Genes (Up and Down)")



Just to be clear, changing scale_color_gradient(low="red", high="blue") +  to scale_color_gradient(low="red", high="blue", breaks = c(0.001, 0.05, 0.1)) + doesn't fix the problem?

No, it gets rid of the p-value scale weirdly... maybe I move my color = padj from aes to separate line?

It's hard to say what the problem is without a minimal reproducible example; are you able to please edit your question with a small example dataset to reproduce the problem @KenH?

I added a sample table that has real values used for the GO plots, hope this is okay.
